# Blank IVR menu in Elastix after adding more entries (options)

Tags: jquery, html, elastix

After creating a simple IVR menu in Elastix 4.0 using its webinterface i added more options to it, e.g. entries like digits which is defined actions when caller will type it.

more than 25 options were okay but when i added more it became blank like this [looks empty like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J43M3.jpg)

I guess it's prgramming logical issue and i decided to find it by inspect element using chrome and it shows the error like following: 
[erorr in google chrome inspector looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWc9k.jpg)

```
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
ivr.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (ivr.js:27)
at j (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @   ivr.js:27
 j  @   jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
 J  @   jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
```

Please anyone help me. I guess it had some restriction in script and i had no idea about it and added more options, how can i fix it back? If i don't have the possibility to delete this menu using buttons how can i remove it manually? 
Thanks in advance, i'd appreciate any suggestions.